# Images for new added or created products in magento have larger size

Tags: php, magento

Magento Ver. 1.9.1.1.
Most of the products are displaying OK in the grid mode. (we don't have any modifications in code like in list.phtml for size specifications).
Looks like every NEW product that we add or create, is being created with a LARGE image size. Even when not adding any images to the product, it creates a large box in the grid display. Even when adding a very small image to the product, the image gets shown big, and distorted.
For other products, the image is displaying ok, but for new ones is not.
(If I add an image to an existing product, as the "small" image, it gets displayed OK) It only happens with new created products.

Any ideas?

[example of new product image being big compared to all others.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wl6ok.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Solved. 
Under my THEME settings in Magento Admin, there was a setting for "Keep Image Aspect Ratio". I changed the setting to NO. Inserted the Image Height
and Width that I wanted. Now everything has exactly the same size, and the resize function is being applied to all images.
Thank you.